# Change the default TaskFactory?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

Is it possible to somehow hook into the creation process of `Task` in TPL?
If I make my own `TaskScheduler`, I can get hold of the `Task` when it is about to be scheduled for execution.
If I make my own `SynchronizationContext`, I can get hold of the continuation when it is about to execute after the `Task` is completed.

But is there some way to set up the default task factory to use my special TaskScheduler?
Or can I somehow apply my task scheduler to be used for any task created in the current thread?

What I would like to do is something like:

```
SetTaskSchedulerForCurrentThread(taskScheduler);

// call code that may or may not use async await or normal tasks...
RunStuff();

UnSetTaskSchedulerForCurrentThread();
```

I've got everything sort of working, I use Task.Factory.StartNew and pass in my custom TaskScheduler.
BUT, I don't want the task that I spin up to use that scheduler, just any potential child task.

Am I out of luck or is it possible to solve?

Comment: All of this shows the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You may get better answer if you can explain what is the core problem you're trying to solve instead of asking what you thought would be the solution.

Comment: It is not good practice to change the scheduler for unrelated code which suspects nothing. Only the piece of code that schedules a task knows where it should run. Why can't you control the scheduler explicitly? Why is this tagged with await?

Comment: I want change default Task.Factory.Scheduler because it shit.